# Rhino service bus programmatic configuration

Tags: esb, rhino-servicebus

I have two hosts - A and B
I use following code snippet to configure service bus in host A.

```
host.BusConfiguration(c => c.Threads(1).Retries(1)
        .Bus(endpointA.AbsoluteUri, "name", true)
        .Receive(typeof(MyMessage).Namespace, hostB.Endpoint.AbsoluteUri, true)
```

This configures host to create bus that listens to e`ndpointA.AbsoluteUri`  address and writes messages from   `[typeof(MyMessage).Namespace]` namespace to  queue located at `hostB.Endpoint.AbsoluteUri` , correct? 
I use same code for configuring if bus in host B (with using of hostB where hostA stands)

I cannot configure two hosts to mutually send and receive messages to each other. Only one of them (A) is able to send messages that are received by B. When B sends message, the message is just put in queue and not consumed by A. What could be a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see what's going on is to turn on logging for log4net to level DEBUG and see what the output is for host A.

Comment: thanks a lot! you simple advice helped me to look into srhino service bus processing pipeline and find an error (minor error in consumer construtor)